# Кнопка удаления Python + TurboGears2

Tags: html, python

Есть хранилище с контроллером:

```
class MemoryController(BaseController):

#some code

@expose('json')
def post_delete(self, uid, **kw):
    memory = DBSession.query(Memory).get(uid)
    DBSession.delete(memory)
    return dict(page='index')
```

Как прикрутить этот метод сюда?

```
<body py:block="body" py:strip="True">
  <div class="main_content">
    <h1>All memories</h1>
    <div><a href="memory/adding">Add memory</a></div><br></br>
    <ul>
      <li py:for="memo in memories">
        <b><div py:content="memo.name"></div></b>
        <div py:content="memo.data"></div>
        <div py:content="memo.user"><p>:</p></div>
        <div py:content="memo.content"></div>

          <form action='{%memory/post_delete%}' method="memo.uid">
            <input type="submit" name="memo.uid" value="Delete"/>
          </form>

        <hr></hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Тоесть нужна кнопка "Delete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, я сам решил проблему. Задача оказалась тривиальной.
В контроллере пишем следующее:

```
@expose('json')
def post_delete(self, uid, **kw):
    memory = DBSession.query(Memory).filter_by(uid=uid).one()
    if not memory:
        return dict(errors={'memory':'Memory not found'})
    DBSession.delete(memory)
    redirect('/memory')
```

Ну а кнопка выгледит так:

```
<form method="POST" action="memory/post_delete" style="display: inline">       
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="$memo.uid"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Спасибо за внимание.